# windows phone 7: How to simulate control click programmatically

Tags: windows-phone-7

windows phone 7: How to simulate control click programmatically on WP7(Silverlight)?

E.g. I want to simulate click the ad banner by clicking a button below.

Thanks,
Yury

Comment: What do you want to achieve? The visual effect of having clicked? or do you want to perform the function that a click would have invoked?

Comment: E.g. I have 3rd party control which do some internal stuff (e.g. run some private method) when user taps it. It does not have public method to invoke it. I need to invoke it programmatically. Therefore I want to simulate click

Comment: eventually you can use reflection to invoke a private method... but in general it is not a good idea to use refelection to call private methods

Answer (score 2):

As of the Mango release, Windows Phone has no support for UI automation.

See also this question for an answer from Jeff Wilcox (MS): [UI Automation for WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137528/ui-automation-for-wp7)