# Silverlight C# - Simulate a Click event on a button

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, click

I have an element with a **Click** method.

I would like to activate that method (or: fake a click on this element) within another function.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you use MVVM design pattern and trying to call it from VM?

Answer (score 1):

No, there currently isnt a way to do this.  See links:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137528/ui-automation-for-wp7

[windows phone 7: How to simulate control click programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241876/windows-phone-7-how-to-simulate-control-click-programmatically)

**EDIT**
This doesnt do exactly what you wanted to do, but you can do something like this and get the same outcome.  I do this type of pattern alot in my code to do get the same outcome.

XAML

```
                <Button Name="testClick" Click="testClick_Click">
                    <TextBlock Text="Click Me"></TextBlock>
                </Button>
```

C#

```
private void testClick_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TestFunction(sender as Button);
    }

private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         //Call same function as button
         TestFunction(testClick);
    }

private void TestFunction(Button bt)
    {
          //do stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your class initiate a RoutedEventArgs:

```
private RoutedEventArgs evnt;
```

Then later call this:

```
element_Click(element, evnt);
```

That should do it.